# Use of eventBus in vertx

Tags: java, javascript, vert.x, event-bus

I am using vertx in my project and I have problems with eventBus. If I understood right, it ables several languages to communicate using one string representing a server route. I have this code in my Server.java:

```
vertx.eventBus().registerHandler("getTree", new Handler<Message<String>>() {
  public void handle(Message<String> e) {
    // e.reply(call of function returning a json string);
  }
});
```

In a javascript file, I need to get that json string just to print it for the moment. I have:

```
var eventBus = require('vertx/event_bus');
eventBus.send('getTree', '', function(reply) {
    console.log('I received a reply ' + reply);
    });
}
```

But nothing happens. Does anyone know why ?

Comment: Can you place more details? is your server up? any errors in logs/

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you would like to see something like `I received a reply` in your console.

In order to be able to receive anything back to your JavaScript reply handler, you will need to change your Java message handler and call `reply` method on the incoming message e.g.

```
vertx.eventBus().registerHandler("getTree", new Handler<Message<String>>() {
  public void handle(Message<String> msg) {
    msg.reply("message from Java handler");
  }
});
```

**Without calling a `reply` method, nothing will happen in your JavaScript sender / reply receiver code.**

After adding the mentioned change to your Java code you should be able to see following logs in console:

> I received a reply message from Java handler

Note that even though you use different languages with Vert.x, entire logic is executed by JVM (JavaScript by Rhino open-source implementation).